# Apache Ignite bus_adraln error during installation of cache

Tags: java, hp-ux, ignite

I have developers that came to me with an interesting issue in regards to Apache Ignite and Java. This is on a `HPUX 11.31 IA platform with Apache-Ignite version 1.3.0-incubating` and our `HP-UX Java build is 1.7.0.13-jinteg_2015_05_22_03_42-b00`. The below error is what has been passed to me but I can't find that Apache-Ignite is supported or tested on `HPUX` and the `BUS_ADRALN` error seems to always result in C++ search hits. Anyway if some light could be shed on what our issue is it would be greatly appreciated as I have spent two days trying to find anything on it.

ERROR

```
"siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (BUS_ADRALN), si_addr=1fffffffa98e8fe9"
```

this is thrown after the call to create the `readyQueue` cache in Ignite. This fatal exception means there is an "invalid address alignment" when trying to memory during the installation of cache.

The developers also sent me a couple logs if that would be of assistance.

A bug in Ignite's Jira for the same issue has been created, the bug has more detailed information about the setup and stack causing the error.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1493

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

This looks very interesting. When writting a class during marshalling Ignite first writes an internal byte flag, followed by some other data. Therefore offset 17 at the moment of crash mentioned in the ticket makes sense: 16 + 1 (our byte).

I have several assumptions here: 
1) We are out of bounds of the array.
2) Byte array element length is not 1.
3) Something else (alignment problem? JMV bug?).

Can you please do the following if possible:
1) Provide GridUnsafeDataOutput.bytes array length at the moment of crash. From the crash report I see that there is some array of length 4096 on the stack. Most probably this is GridUnsafeDataOutput.bytes, but we need to be 100% sure.
2) Run the following program on affected machine and provide the output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sun.misc.Unsafe unsafe = org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.unsafe();

    System.out.println(unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(byte[].class));
    System.out.println(unsafe.arrayIndexScale(byte[].class));
}
```

This way we will know runtime JVM array parameters.